# SML list decomposition issue

Tags: list, sml, decomposition

I found the old U of Washington course *CSE341: Programming Languages* and am trying to follow along just so I can one day tackle Paulson's *ML for the Working Programmer*. So I have this:

```
fun number_in_month5 (m : int, ms : (int*int*int) list) =
    List.length (List.filter (fn (_,x2,_) => x2 = m) ms)
```

which gives me back a list of matching 3-tuples. I can throw a `List.length` on the front and get the count. But what about this

```
fun number_in_month6 (m, (_,d2,_) :: ms) =
    List.length (List.filter (fn (_,x2,_) => x2 = m) ms)

: stdIn:279.36 Warning: calling polyEqual
: stdIn:278.5-279.43 Warning: match nonexhaustive
:           (m,(_,d2,_) :: ms) => ...
:   
: val number_in_month6 = fn : ''a * ('b * ''a * 'c) list -> ('b * ''a * 'c) list
```

Testing gives bad answers sometimes

```
- number_in_month6  (2,[(2018,2,1),(2018,2,2),(2018,1,3),(2018,2,4)])
val it = 2 : int
```

Why is this not working? But then I have no skill in reading an ML error message. Somebody advised *not* declaring types at the start of the function -- and I tried and failed to do this. Then I found this

```
fun sumlists [] [] : int list = []
    |   sumlists (n :: ns) (m :: ms) = (n + m) :: sumlists ns ms;

    ;;; ML WARNING - Clauses of function declaration are non-exhaustive
    ;;; CONTEXT  :  fun sumlists
    val sumlists = fn : int list -> int list -> int list
```

> The definition leaves an expression such as `sumlists [1] [];`
>   undefined.

So I understand the concept of non-exhaustive, but I can't fathom why my function is non-exhaustive and giving bad answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> fun number_in_month6 (m, (_,d2,_) :: ms) =
> List.length (List.filter (fn (_,x2,_) => x2 = m) ms)
>
> : stdIn:279.36 Warning: calling polyEqual
> : stdIn:278.5-279.43 Warning: match nonexhaustive
> :           (m,(_,d2,_) :: ms) => ...
> :   
> : val number_in_month6 = fn : ''a * ('b * ''a * 'c) list -> ('b * ''a * 'c) list
> ```
>
> I can't fathom why my function is non-exhaustive and giving bad answers.

- Non-exhaustive: there exists a value which the pattern `(_,d2,_) :: ms` will not match, which is `[]`. The problem seems to be that you pattern match on the input of `number_in_month6` at all when you actually only need to do this inside the predicate function to `List.filter`.

  Maybe the misconception here is that "the input won't be a list of 3-tuples if I don't pattern match in the argument, since I removed type annotations". It may be interesting to know that SML's type inference is strong enough to infer that `ms` is a list of 3-tuples simply by using `List.filter` and `fn (_,month2,_) => ...`.
- Bad answers: The result is off by one sometimes because you throw away the first element, `(_,d2,_)`, and see how long the filtered remainder of the list, `ms`, is.

  In your example the first date is supposed to be counted as part of the correct result, 3, but instead it is discarded, and the remaining 2 out of 3 dates are counted correctly.

Fixing this:

```
fun number_in_month (month1, dates) =
    List.length (List.filter (fn (_, month2, _) => month1 = month2) dates)
```

And testing this:

```
- number_in_month6 (2,[(2018,2,1),(2018,2,2),(2018,1,3),(2018,2,4)]);
> val it = 3 : int
```

Some points: Giving your variables better names makes it easier to understand what's going on. You may want to consider using a record instead of a tuple. They're basically the same, except tuples have numbered entries and records have named entries, and record syntax is a bit more complicated. But the upside is that you don't accidentally forget if this is American, European or ISO dates:

```
type date = { year : int, month : int, day : int }

fun number_in_month (month1, dates : date list) =
    List.length (List.filter (fn ({ month = month2, ... }) => month1 = month2) dates)

val test_1 = number_in_month (2, [ { year = 2018, month = 2, day = 1 }
                                 , { year = 2018, month = 2, day = 2 }
                                 , { year = 2018, month = 1, day = 3 }
                                 , { year = 2018, month = 2, day = 4 }
                                 ])
```

Record syntax can be a bit tricky, though, so feel free to continue with tuples for as long as you find them practical.